# Angular, ng-repeat not working in same paragraph

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use `ng-repeat` inside a paragraph `<p>` tag. But it is not working.
Below is my code:

```
  <div class="section">
    <p class="text-left">
      <strong>Designation:</strong>{{showData.Designation}}&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong>Company:</strong> &nbsp;{{showData.Company}}&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <b ng-repeat="location in showData.City">Location:</b>&nbsp;{{location}}</p>
  </div>
```

However if I wish to implement `ng-repeat` in next paragraph it is working. But I want entire things to be in one line. Any suggestion, why it is not working and how should I put `ng-repeat` in above code.

**Edit:** I tried below code from one answer

```
<b ng-repeat="location in showData.City">Location: {{location}}</b>
```

However it is causing two problems

First

> I expect result to be like **Location:**  Banglore,  India
>
> while it is giving  **Location:  Banglore,  Location: India**

Second I don't want my value to be in bold letters.

Comment: Can you please show me  the data in showData.City?

Comment: check my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40722618/2545680)

Comment: Make no sense. India is not a city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="section">
    <p class="text-left">
        <strong>Designation:</strong>{{showData.Designation}}&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <strong>Company:</strong> &nbsp;{{showData.Company}}
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        Location: <span ng-repeat="location in showData.City">{{location}}</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

If you need to show the cities, you can just join the entries in your controller and show them:

```
this.citiesJoined = showData.City.join(",");
```

HTML

```
Location: Location: {{citiesJoined}}
```

Comment: It seem to be working fine. taking some time to test and understand.

Comment: In this case dont use ng-repeat. just join your array with coma and display it

Comment: @simon, yeah, that would be another options, thanks, I'll add it there

Comment: Thanks for helping me with so much knowledge, this is my first Angular app.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap it inside `</b>`

```
<b ng-repeat="location in showData.City">Location: {{location}}</b>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/grvBJovYnOfpOsDEPAQe?p=preview)**

Comment: I have edited my question, as I am having two issues with this solution. Could you please sugget.